# asp ModalPopupExtender load a complet new website?

Tags: ajax, modalpopupextender

I will use the ModalPopupExtender, I downloaded it and tried a little bit.

How can I show a complet new ASP-Page and not only a Panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an `<iframe>` element inside your panel, load the other page inside that frame and extend the panel with your `ModalPopupExtender` as usual:

```
<asp:Panel ID="yourPanel" runat="server">
    <iframe src="yourOtherPage.aspx"></iframe>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="yourPopupButton" runat=server />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="yourModalPopup" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="yourPopupButton" PopupControlID="yourPanel" />
```